# Multiple selects VS LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query with two different forms of doing it, I have tried both, but the first is faster than other, however I have read that subqueries are good for the performance, then I want to know why the first one was executed in lesser time, and which is the better option.

I have a query seams to:

```
    SELECT count(*) as cantProductos,
(select count(*) from Table2 
    join Table1 on Table2.idT=Table1.idT
    where Table2.state=3
) as cant1,
(select count(*) from table2 
    join otherTable
    where otherTable.origin=10
) as cant2 FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.state=1
```

But I change with that

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN  Table1.state=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cantProducts
SUM(CASE WHEN table2.state=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cant1,
SUM(CASE WHEN otherTable.origin=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cant2 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN  table2 on Table2.idT=Table1.idT
LEFT JOIN  otherTable on 0=0
```

Comment: Can you please post the explain plan for both the queries?